# how to print sum of primes in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print `sum` of primes in a list in Python?

I'm a new to Python, therefore I might be making a terrible mistake.

Please help out.

```
def prime(n):

    i = 2
    c = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if(n%i == 0):
            c = c+1
    if(c == 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def sumprimes(l1):

    l1 = []
    l = len(l1)
    i = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,l):
        if(prime(l1[i]) is True):
            sum = sum +l1[i]
print(sum)

l1 = [3,4,5,6]

print(sumprimes(l1))
```

Output should be equal to 8.

Comment: You cannot print `sum` because it is in `sumprimes` scope. And `sumprimes` doesn't return anything so you can't print it that way either.

Comment: If you are passing `l1` to `sumprimes` as an argument, don't start `sumprimes` by `l1 = []` (which just deletes your data). Also, `if(prime(l1[i]) is True):` should just be `if prime(l1[i]):` Finally -- why use indices as all? Just use `for num in l1:`

Comment: Tangential to your programming question, but you are using one of the worst possible ways to test if a number is prime. At the very least, you should use that a number `n > 2` is prime if and only if it is odd and has no odd divisors in the range `3` to the square root of `n`. To certify if a number below 1,000,000 is prime, your code takes up to 1,000,000 steps, but no more than 500 are ever needed (and clever optimizations are able to reduce that even further)

Answer (score 4):

```
def prime(n):

    i = 2
    c = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if(n%i == 0):
            c = c+1
    if(c == 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def sumprimes(l1):

    sum=0
    for x in l1:
        if prime(x):
            sum += x
    return sum

l1 = [3,4,5,6]

print(sumprimes(l1))
```

Use the above code. You need to use the return statement to print the result of a function. And there is no need for your range() loop, there is a more elegant way to do this in python, use a for loop over all elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using below code too.

```
lst = [1,2,5,7,9,10,12]

def isPrime(x):
    if x == 1:
        return False
    for i in range(2,x-1):
        if x%i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def getPrimeSum(l):
    l = [i for i in l if isPrime(i)]
    return sum(l)

print(getPrimeSum(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Check and add into the list of primeval numbers (all primeval number under a specific number)
H = int(input("What the maxium number?: "))
RangeFinding = list(range(3, H+1))
import math
Prime = [2]
for a in RangeFinding:
  x = True
  y = 2
  while x:
    NCanA = math.floor(math.sqrt(a))
    if a %y == 0:
      print(f'{a} is not prime')
      x = False
    else:
      if y > NCanA:
        print(f'{a} is prime')
        Prime.append(a)
        x = False
      else:
        y = y + 1
        x = True
print(Prime)
```

Comment: adding a  short simple explanation would be great

Answer (score 0):

```py
#**this function will check weather number is prime or not**
def prime(k):
    i = 2
    j = 0
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        if(k % i == 0):
            j = j + 1
    if(j == 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#**this function will add all prime numbers**
def sumOfPrimes(l1):
    sum=0
    for y in l1:
        if prime(y):
            sum += y
    return sum

list1 = [3,4,5,6]

print(sumOfPrimes(list1))
```

```
**You Will get output as 8**
```

Explain

1. I have created a function prime() that will check whether numbers are prime or not.
2. I have created a function sumOfPrime() that will add all the prime numbers.
3. list1
   4)Called the function sumOfPrime(list1)

I have shared a Screenshot of the [code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bzL0.png)Program and Output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).